# WSO2 apim - add custom roles while creating a new Tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, roles, multi-tenant

In WSO2 APIM 3.1.0, I can create roles for carbon.super and for each tenant I create. I want that whenever I create a new tenant from Tenant Mngt API, some custom roles get defined automatically for that new tenant. I cannot use roles API to create roles after creating a tenant because the server will not have tenant credentials hence I cannot use SOAP request for creating roles in a tenant.

Is there any config file where I can add my custom roles and they get defined automatically for all the new tenants I create?